# MySQL LIKE IN with Input Parameter of stored procedure Comma Separated Values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, like, string-searching

I am creating a stored procedure to search user's Towns. 
From the User Interface user will select multiple towns that will be sent to the stored procedure.
Sample input of the towns parameter for the stored procedure would be like `orangi,faisal,nazimabad`.

Towns that are stored in the table are

- Orangi
- Korangi
- Shah Faisal
- Shahrah-e-Faisal
- Nazimabad
- North Nazimabad

Now I want to select all those above records against that input. That is I want to use `LIKE` operator with `IN` from a stored procedure's parameter.

I don't know how many towns would be there in the input.
it could be just one, or two or three or all these mentioned above.

I want to search all the towns against that query

Sample Stored Procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetUsersByTown`(
IN `SearchTowns` VARCHAR(200) -- `ORANGI,FAISAL,NAZIMABAD`
)
BEGIN
      SELECT
      name,
      Town,
      FROM userLocation where Town in (SearchTowns)
END
```

Expected Outcome

- Name ---  Town
- Hamza --- Orangi
- Jamal --- Korangi
- Hasham --- Shah Faisal
- Aliyan --- Shahrah-e-Faisal
- Danish --- Nazimabad
- Farrukh --- North Nazimabad

I have tried to use `find_in_set()` but FIND_IN_SET does not accept wildcards like `%` and it doesn't use index?

I have also looked at using `REGEXP  ValueA|ValueB` but I don't know how to put the input parameter that is comma separated values in that REGEXP

Comment: Use FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Akina, but That doesn't work with wildcards and I guess with index also ?

Comment: Program a loop which runs over all searchtowns and construct a select statement,PREPARE  stmt which adds for every city a Where town LIKE '%searchcity%' it os a bit tricky because you must link them with OR but doable.

Comment: @nbk can you show me a snippet to get started from ?

Comment: You say `orangi,faisal,nazimabad` is the input?  What should the output be?

Comment: @RickJames, I am expecting the output to include `'Orangi', 'Korangi', 'Shah Faisal', 'Shahrah-e-Faisal', 'Nazimabad', 'North Nazimabad'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `REPLACE(SearchTowns, ',', '|')` to change commas to pipes.
- Put that result in, say, `@regexp`.
- Construct, via `CONCAT` a single `SELECT` with

  ```
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
    name,
    Town,
    FROM userLocation where Town REGEXP "', @regexp, '"');
  ```
- `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` the query.

That query should look like:

```
SELECT
      name,
      Town,
      FROM userLocation where Town REGEXP "orangi|faisal|nazimabad"
```

(You could manually run that to verify that the correct rows are delivered.)

Also, be sure to have case-folding `COLLATION`, such as `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` for `Town`.  (That is indicated by the trailing `_ci`.)

**Code**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetUsersByTown`(
    IN `SearchTowns` VARCHAR(200) -- `ORANGI,FAISAL,NAZIMABAD`
)
BEGIN
IF (SearchTowns IS NULL) THEN
    SELECT name, Town
        FROM userLocation;
ELSE
    SET @towns = REPLACE(SearchTowns, ',', '|');
    SELECT name, Town
        FROM userLocation
        WHERE Town REGEXP (@towns);
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this solution may require check for sql injection

Comment: SET \@sql = 'SELECT
  name,
  Town,
  FROM userLocation where Town REGEXP ?';
EXECUTE @sql USING @regexp;

Comment: @RickJames, can you please show the complete procedure ?

Comment: Why do I have to Prepare and Execute the query? Like why we have to create the query in string format first and then use prepare and execute to that query? why can't we directly use the query?

Comment: How can I make it to return all records if the parameter is null?

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada - I found a way to avoid prepare+execute.

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada - and I added the NULL code.

Comment: Clean and simple. Answer accepted and +1

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE `GetUsersByTown`(
IN `SearchTowns` LONGTEXT
)
BEGIN
      SELECT
      name,
      Town,
      FROM userLocation where FIND_IN_SET(Town,(SearchTowns))>0
END

Comment: Hello @Koteswara, Welcome to StackExchange, As I have mentioned in the question, Find_In_SET does not accept wildcards hence that will return only Exact matches

Comment: you can try this

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE GetUsersByTown( IN SearchTowns LONGTEXT ) BEGIN 
SELECT name, Town, FROM userLocation t
inner join (select Town from userLocation where find_in_set(Town,(SearchTowns))>0) n ON t.Town like concat(n.Town,'%')

END

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the updated code? so that I can have a better look and what you are trying to say

Comment: @KoteswaraRao this procedure will not return users from Korangi if searching string  doesn't contain this town but contains Orangi, or if it contains only part of town name from the middle

Answer (score 0):

This is a stored procedure which splits inputed comma-separated string (SearchTowns) into separate rows, inserts these rows into temporary table (Towns) and then uses join between userLocation and Towns tables on required conditions (where userLocation.town is like %town% from Towns table). All other rows which don't correspond this condition will be eliminated from the final resultset.
Also I used DISTINCT to avoid rows duplication in case if userLocation.town corresponds to more than one row from Towns table. For example, if SearchTowns contains 'Orangi' and 'Korangi' then users who are located in Korangi will be joined with both towns (because 'korangi' like '%orangi%').

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUsersByTown(SearchTowns VARCHAR(200))

    BEGIN
      DECLARE pos INT Default 0 ;
      DECLARE str VARCHAR(200);
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Towns(town VARCHAR(200));
      #Loop through comma-separated values
      #pos - is the number of current word within search string
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET pos=pos+1;
         SET str=REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SearchTowns, ',', pos),
                    LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SearchTowns, ',', pos -1)) + 1),
                    ',', '');
         IF str='' THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
         #Do Inserts into temp table here with str going into the row
         insert into Towns values (str);
    END LOOP simple_loop;
    SELECT DISTINCT
      u.name,
      u.Town
    FROM userLocation AS u
    JOIN Towns AS t ON u.Town LIKE CONCAT('%', t.town, '%');
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE Towns;
END
```

Comment: Please explain your answer @Nikita

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada added an explanation

Comment: Thankyou for the code Nikita, I will accept the answer shortly after testing all the results